# JavaScript function minimising?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Is there anyway to minimize the JavaScript function coding where functions / the call procedure are identical?  I'm not entirely sure a good way to explain it but here is the code below...

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
$( '#CartDialog' ).dialog( {
    autoOpen:false,
    title:"Shopping Cart",
    width:600,
    minWidth:600,
    maxWidth:600,
    minHeight:300,
    maxHeight:600,
    modal:true,
    show:{effect: "blind"},
    hide:{effect: "fade"}
    });
$('#CartLink').on( 'click', function() {
    $( '#CartDialog' ).dialog('open');
});
});
$(function() {
$( '#LoginDialog' ).dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    title:"Login / Register",
    width:650,
    maxWidth:650,
    height:250,
    maxHeight:600,
    resizable:false,
    modal:true,
    show:{effect: "blind"},
    hide:{effect: "fade"}
});
$('#LoginLink').on( 'click', function() {
    $( '#LoginDialog' ).dialog('open');
});
});
$(function() {
$( '#LogoutDialog' ).dialog( {
    autoOpen:false,
    title:"Logout Confirmation",
    width:250,
    height:250,
    resizable:false,
    modal:true,
    show:{effect: "blind"},
    hide:{effect: "fade"}
    });
$('#LogoutDialog').on( 'click', function() {
    $( '#LogoutDialog' ).dialog('open');
});
});
$(function() {
$( '#MyAccountDialog' ).dialog( {
    autoOpen:false,
    title:"Login / Register",
    width:600,
    minWidth:600,
    maxWidth:600,
    minHeight:300,
    maxHeight:600,
    modal:true
    });
$('#MyAccountDialog').on( 'click', function() {
    $( '#MyAccountDialog' ).dialog('open');
});
});
```

Main Doc Idea:

```
<div class="TopShortLinks" id"CartDialog"></div>
<div class="TopShortLinks" id"LoginDialog"></div>
<div class="TopShortLinks" id"LogoutDialog"></div>
<div class="TopShortLinks" id"MyAccountDialog"></div>
```

I've been trying to tinker with the idea of calling the class then using the div id to propose to a central javascript function (if possible) in order to determine the correct data to display as at current it looks very much repeated.

Hope it's easy to understand.

Comment: Do you mean "javascript function" when you say "java function"? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes I do mean a Javascript function, sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: to start you can remove '$(function() {})' wrapper from every function and the wrap everything in only one '$(function() {})'

Comment: although @Lix suggestion is really great , but i want to explain one thing while we're at it  . jQuery in general is minimal coding , it's hard to make it more minimal than what it already is . the central idea of making code writing minimal is to find what is repeated in the code and make it shorter .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I suggest doing is defining one function that will be used to initiate all of the dialog windows:

```
function show_dialog( selector, settings ){
  var default_settings = {
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    minWidth:600,
    minHeight:30,
    ...
  }
  $.extend( default_settings, settings );
  $( selector ).dialog( default_settings );
}
```

You will pass the selector for the relevant DOM element and an object containing all the unique settings for each dialog. Within the function, there is a `default_settings` object defined - this contains all of the settings that are identical across all calls but the settings object that is passed to the function can override these defaults by using the [`$.extend()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) which "merges" objects.

Example usage:

```
show_dialog( "#CartDialog", {
    minWidth:700,
    maxWidth:500,
    minHeight:100,
    maxHeight:800
} );
```

This function call will use `#CartDialog` as its selector and override the default `minWidth` and `minHeight` with the values that are passed. All other settings defined in `show_dialog` will remain the same, `modal`, `autoOpen`, etc...

Comment: Much neater :) Thanks for your help